# jQuery nuSelectable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the jQuery nuSelectable plugin to allow users to select multiple items at once. Somehow I can't get it to make the selection though. The plugin is from here: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Select-Multiple-Elements-with-Mouse-nuSelectable.html

On selection the numbers are supposed to change color, but on click nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
        <div id="item-container" class="text-center">
        <div class="row element-medium-top element-medium-bottom">
            <div class="selectIconBox ">
              <div class="item iconWrap">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="selectIconBox ">
                  <div class="item iconWrap">2</div>
              </div>
              <div class="selectIconBox ">
                  <div class="item iconWrap">3</div>
              </div>
              <div class="selectIconBox ">
                  <div class="item iconWrap">4</div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.iconWrap-selected {
    background-color:#6a989e;
}
.iconWrap {
    border: 2px solid #101820;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 17px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color:#101820;
    position:relative
}
#item-container .iconWrap {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.selectIconBox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px 80px;
}
```

JS:

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.nu-selectable.js"></script> 
<script>
$('#item-container').nuSelectable({
  items: '.item',
  selectionClass: 'selectIconBox',
  selectedClass: 'iconWrap-selected',
  autoRefresh: true
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like it works when you drag the item and not when you click on it. Your code works fine. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdyknjac/

Comment: thanks for looking into this for me. So how do I change it from "drag" to "click"? Any thoughts?

Comment: also: the drag only works in your fiddle, but not on my page. Did you do anything different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want alike this:

**1)** Added `.selectable` class along your `.selectIconBox` class in your **HTML**.

**2)** Removed your **JavaScript** and `.iconWrap-selected { background-color:#6a989e;}` from **CSS**.

**3)** Added `.selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }` to your **CSS**.

**4)** Replaced your **JQuery** with `$( ".selectable" ).selectable();`.

```js
$(".selectable").selectable();
```

```css
.iconWrap {
    border: 2px solid #101820;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 17px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color:#101820;
    position:relative
}
#item-container .iconWrap {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.selectIconBox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px 80px;
}

.selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="item-container" class="text-center">
  <div class="row element-medium-top element-medium-bottom">
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note :** You could change `background-color` of selection by changing value in `.ui-selected` class in your CSS. Also you can not change name of that particular class(i.e. `.ui-selected`).

**Source:** [JQuery User Interface](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/)

### **Update :**

**Follow Up Answer:**  As mentioned in below comment.

```js
$(".selectable").selectable();

// Onclick on .submit class or whatever class you define. 

$(".submit").click(function()
{
  var selectedArr = []; // Declaring an Array

  $(".selectable").each(function() // Fidns each element that has .selectable class 
  {
    // Finds inside each .selectable class for .ui-slected class and on getting takes value inside it.
    var selectedNum = $(this).find('.ui-selected').text(); 
    //Converts it into Integer
    var intNum = parseInt(selectedNum);
    // If the slected value is number pushes into array.
    if (!isNaN(intNum)) {
      selectedArr.push(intNum);
    }    
  });
  alert(selectedArr); /*So now when you click on submit the Array "selectedArr" has selected Numbers*/
});
```

```css
.iconWrap {
    border: 2px solid #101820;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 17px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color:#101820;
    position:relative
}
#item-container .iconWrap {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.selectIconBox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 80px;
}

.selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="item-container" class="text-center">
  <div class="row element-medium-top element-medium-bottom">
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="selectIconBox selectable">
      <div class="item iconWrap">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="submit">Submit : Alert! Selected</button>
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Comment: Quick follow up question: would you happen to know how I can turn my code into a form that sends off the selected numbers on submit at the end?

Comment: Yes, just find the elements that have the class `.ui-selected` and find corresponding `innerHTML` or `text()`.

Comment: Sounds easy enough, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Can you show me an example by chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with jQuery UI.

Check this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL8pLmzy/).

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul class="items">
    <li class="item">1</li>
    <li class="item">2</li>
    <li class="item">3</li>
    <li class="item">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".items").selectable({filter:"li"});
```

CSS:

```
.items{
    width:400;
    height:500;
    overflow:auto;
}
.item{
    color:#fff;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:cyan;
    margin:15px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
.ui-selected{
    background-color:green !important;  
}
```